# Windows Azure VIP Swap, how to handle custom web.config values?

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config

It's easy to publish a new deployment to a Cloud Service's Staging or Production environment, but I'd like to use the VIP Swap (swapping Production and Staging deployments) more often. In my case, I have different web.config values for each environment. For instance, on staging my web.config may have:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionStringName" value="StagingConnectionString" />
    <add key="WCFServiceUrl" value="http://somelongGUID.cloudapp.net/" />
</appSettings>
```

...and on Production, I would have:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionStringName" value="ProductionConnectionString" />
    <add key="WCFServiceUrl" value="http://prodservice.cloudapp.net/" />
</appSettings>
```

When publishing to Staging or Production, the web.config gets transformed using the correct values based on either Debug or Release. But when it comes to VIP Swap on the Windows Azure portal, I would have to trigger the swap, then remote into each instance and manually change those values (which is definitely not the proper way to do it).

What could be done to better handle this situation? Or is there a better and more flexible solution to handle those custom config values than to have them in web.config (especially in this case)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you using the `WCFServiceUrl` setting in your application?

Comment: @Tragedian For example, the WCFServiceUrl for Production, is the Production URL of another Azure Cloud Service. Staging has a different URL too.

Comment: I was thinking maybe I can utilize the Azure Table Storage (if possible) to save those config settings there and pull them accordingly based on either Production or Staging. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to determine if I am in prod or staging as far as I know.

Answer (score 5):

Using VIP swap is considered the "standard" way to promote staging to production in web and worker roles. It's achieves this swap by changing the Azure routing to point the "production" URL to the "staging" role instance and pointing the "staging" URL to the "production" role instance.

Internally, the roles aren't aware of this change: it happens entirely externally to the hosting process.

If you want to use VIP swaps in this way, you should consider changing your application to either be unaware of its host environment, or that it reads the information from its host whenever it needs to know it.

---

The way Production and Staging are arranged up in Azure, the packages should both be the same: both live configurations. The feature is intended for high-availability deployment; it doesn't cater for the kind of testing that would be implied by having the role call out to a different service depending on whether it's a staging deployment or not.

You'd be better using a separate role to perform tests against; staging should only be used to test that your deployment is successful before you make the switch with the current production deployment.

Answer (score 2):

VIP swap as the name suggest is Virtual IP swap. So i think this is simple changing the DNS pointers to the machine IP, so I don't think any config transformation can happen.The staging deployment should match in every sense to the production deployment.

If you want to test the deployment against a different configuration then better create an new service in Azure and deploy you solution there with the stage configuration. Once satisfied do a new deployment in the production's stage slot. Do a quick smoke and do a swap.

Comment: So far, we've been using the Staging environment as a place to stage our newly added features to the application and bug fixes. It seems that we have to rethink this where we create a Cloud Service dedicated entirely to a production deployment that can be staged and yet another Cloud Service dedicated to our staging deployments. At least that's what I understood from what you wrote. Are we on the same page?

Comment: Yes! That's right. One Service for Production and one for Staging. Production stage slot can be used to provide VIP swap with minimal down time and to do smoke testing and nothing else and can be bought down after that. So cost wise there is a parity.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches you can consider.

For a web role, you can differentiate between staging and production by examining the host name in the incoming request URL. By recognising the context from the host name, you can use different configuration values. So you have both connection strings in your web.config and you change the code to use the appropriate one based on the host name, for example.

Alternatively, rather than VIP-swapping via the portal, write a tool, such as a Powershell Cmdlet, to do it and have that trigger a configuration change at the same time as performing the actual swap.

The VIP-swap, itself, is just a reconfiguration of the Load Balancer.

EDIT: Here's some code that I massaged from a different app (I actually use this logic to differentiate between tenants in a multi-tenant app, but the principle is the same).

```
public class DeploymentContextModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += OnBegin;
    }

    void OnBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = sender as HttpApplication;

        if (app != null)
        {
            var ctx = app.Context;

            if (ctx != null)
            {
                var req = ctx.Request;

                if (req != null)
                {
                    var url = req.Url;

                    var hostName = url.Host;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName))
                    {
                        ctx.Items["DeploymentContext"] = 
                            DeploymentContext.Find(hostName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you'll need to come up with an implementation of `DeploymentContext.Find(hostname)` to map the hostname to some useful data. For the production slot, the hostname will be that associated with your cloud service. For the staging slot, it will be a guid (without hyphens).

Configure it into web.config as follows:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="DeploymentContextModule"
       type="MyNamespace.DeploymentContextModule, MyNamespace" 
       preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

Throughout your app, you can use `httpContext.Items["DeploymentContext"]` to identify your deployment slot and read the correct configuration settings, accordingly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to examine the host name in the incoming request? Even though the WCF URL is in the configuration file, it doesn't mean it's static since those relate to Azure Cloud Services and the URL (especially in staging) can change.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth taking a look at the CloudConfigurationManager class, that looks at the csfg configuration settings, or the web.config.  This would allow you to define your settings in the ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg file and edit them from the Azure Portal before swaping your VIPs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx